# a rule for Prolog predicate half_sister_of(X,Y)?

Tags: prolog

The kb is

```
parent_of(john,ann).
parent_of(mary,ann).
parent_of(mary,sylvia).
parent_of(brian,sylvia).

female(sylvia).
female(ann).


?-Half_sister_of(X,Y).
X=ann
X=sylvia ;

X=sylvia
X=ann
```

Comment: The example you show is invalid and would generate an error. A predicate in Prolog cannot begin with a capital letter. You should think about what a half sister is. If you can define a half-sister (in words), then you write your Prolog predicate to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
half_sister_of(X,Y) :-
    parent_of(A,X),
    parent_of(A,Y),
    parent_of(B,X),
    parent_of(C,Y),
    not(A = B),
    not(A = C),
    not(B = C),
    female(Y).
```

In order for Y to be a half-sister of X, they must share one parent (A), and not share the other parents (B and C), and Y must be female.

Answer (score 0):

Half_sister_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
female(Y),
parent_of(Z,X),
parent_of(Z,Y),
parent_of(B,X),
parent_of(C,Y),
Z /= B,
Z /= C,
B /= C.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).